# Эфективное рисование PNG из ресурсов

Tags: c++, winapi, png, gdi, gdi+

Здавствуйте! Всё время пользовался кодом, предоставленным в статье RSDN
 **"Gdi+.Графика нового поколения"**

https://rsdn.ru/?article/gdi/gdiplus1.xml

```
Bitmap* BitmapFromResource(HINSTANCE hInstance,
           LPCTSTR szResName, LPCTSTR szResType)
{
  HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(hInstance, szResName, szResType);
  if(!hrsrc) return 0;
  // "ненастоящий" HGLOBAL - см. описание LoadResource
  HGLOBAL hgTemp = LoadResource(hInstance, hrsrc);
  DWORD sz = SizeofResource(hInstance, hrsrc);
  void* ptrRes = LockResource(hgTemp);
  HGLOBAL hgRes = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, sz);
  if(!hgRes) return 0;
  void* ptrMem = GlobalLock(hgRes);
  // Копируем растровые данные
  CopyMemory(ptrMem, ptrRes, sz);
  GlobalUnlock(hgRes);
  IStream *pStream;
  // TRUE означает освободить память при последнем Release
  HRESULT hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hgRes, TRUE, &pStream);
  if(FAILED(hr))
  {
    GlobalFree(hgRes);
    return 0;
  }
  // Используем загрузку из IStream
  Bitmap *image = Bitmap::FromStream(pStream);
  pStream->Release();
  return image;
}
```

Рисую по-стандарту

```
 Graphics g(hdc);
 g.DrawImage(BitmapFromResource(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(101),"PNG"),500,500)
```

Проблема заключается в производительности. Изображения русуются недопустипо медленно(маленькие ещё нормально, но вот картинка 600 на 200, к примеру, будет рисоваться **аж секунду**(плюс-минус:) )). Может кто-нибудь знает более производительный вариант рисования **PNG из ресурсов, не используя сторонние библиотеки**. Буду благодарен.

**Обновлено**

Я немного изменил функцию. Добавил двумерный `static` массив куда сохранял модуль, имя и сам `Bitmap*`. Сначала идёт проверка: если имя и модуль совпадают, то возвращаем уже ранее занесённый `Bitmap*`, и всё. Если нет  - проделываем, то что писали на RSDN, добавляем данные в массив.

Как оказалось дело не в нахождении(ведь мы теперь находим лишь один раз), а в самом методе класса `Graphics::DrawImage`. Всё-таки этот метод рисует медленно

Как быть?

Comment: Долго идёт загрузка, а не само рисование.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я понял, и  как ускорить? Может есть альтернативные методы?

Comment: Поищите в нете декомпрессоры png source.  Если хорошего не найдёте, можно попробовать zip-deflate алгоритм найти, поправить что б таблица халфмана была одним куском в памяти или найти с пулами. Открытые алгоритмы есть - их можно поправить.

Comment: @nick_n_a Хмм, почитаю, спасибо

Comment: При каждом вызова `g.DrawImage(BitmapFromResource(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(101),"PNG"),500,500)` из ресурсов подгружается новый битмап и сразу же утекает. Вызывайте `BitmapFromResource` только один раз и используйте возвращаемое значение для всех последующих вызовов рисования, а под конец не забудьте удалить.

Comment: @VTT, спасибо но уже разобрался давно